# Css not loading with pages in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working with nextjs,I am trying to display "blog detail"(using slug),
Whenever i move "[slug].js" inside "pages" folder then code is working fine but whenever i move
this file to inside "blog"(inside page) folder then after refesh page "css" not loading, In other
words whenever i move file to "folder" (inside page folder) then css not working after refresh page,
I tried with following code

```
<Link href={`/${post.slug}`}>
    <a className="rdmre-btn"> Read More</a>
 </Link>
```

Here is my [slug.js]

```
import Axios from "axios";
import  {useRouter}  from "next/router";
import LatestBlogs from "../components/LatestBlogs/LatestBlogs";
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import Header from '../components/Layout/Header'

const Post = ({ post }) => {

return (
        //my code
);
};
```

Comment: @Jalal css is already importing "document.js" should i again import "css" in component file also ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your `.next` folder and restarting your dev server? If you open the network tab in devtools do you see the failing request to the CSS file? Can you post the URL of the failing file?